# When I ajax post json data but also received null

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I try so many times to do below these code . but it still recive the value is null.

```
        var cartViewModel = []; 
        $(":text").each(function (i) {
        var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
        var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        cartViewModel.push({ id: id, quantity: quantity });     
        }

        and next I use $.post to submit cartViewModel
        the code such like:  

        var data= { data: JSON.stringify(cartViewModel) };
          $.post(url,data,function(json){
            //....
          });   


    public class ShoppingCartViewModel
    {        

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitCart(List<ShoppingCartViewModel> models)
        {         

            return Json(result);
        }
```

but the arg 'models' also is null, I feel very confused. who can point out the right way. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binder is expecting a property named models, but you're using the name `data`. What happens if you change

```
var data= { data: JSON.stringify(cartViewModel) };
```

to

```
var data= { models: JSON.stringify(cartViewModel) };
```

Edit:

The reason your models property is now empty is because you're calling `JSON.stringify(cartViewModel)`. Instead of passing the action an array of objects, your passing it a string (that happens to be a representation of an array of objects).

Change your data definition to:

```
var data = { models: cartViewModel };
```

Edit again:

The above works fine for MVC5. It does not work in MVC4. To make it work in MVC4:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ models: cartViewModel }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
});
```

Comment: can you help me about the count is zero?

Comment: Yes, sec, I need to run it in VS to check something

Comment: Thanks a lot. now the count is correct. but I found ever item the id :0 quantion:0.  why ?  I'm sure the cartViewModel is like  [{"id":11,"quantity":10},{"id":22,"quantity":5},{"id":23,"quantity":1},{"‌​id":33,"quantity":1},{"id":44,"quantity":1},{"id":55,"quantity":4}]

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing all the code. Try changing id and quantity to Id and Quantity in the Javascript side, to make sure it binds properly. But beyond that, I'd set a breakpoint on the $.post() and make sure you're posting the right data. You should also try a test with fixed data: cartViewModel.push({ id: 1, quantity: 13 }); to figure out where it's failing.

Comment: I just change the id to Id, quantity to Quantity. but still can not get the correct value ,also still is 0.  In this post, I think I've write almost the code. and I try to debug it so many times. but can not how to do it?

Comment: I try to console.log the data before $.ajax. I'm sure the console is like :models [object{Id=11, Quantity=10},object{Id=22, Quantity=5},......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72872/discussion-between-mfanto-and-tiancaolin).